# GoLang - GoQuery HTML Insertion Fails

Tags: html, go, goquery

I wish to extract `elementB`, and then stop before element `C` and `D` - i.e., do not extract the `.text` of content `elementC` and `elementD`. However, I only know how to extract the entire div text, using `Contents().Not` to ignore `elementC`, but `elementD` is still captured.

Here is the code I am currently using:

GoLang:

```
capturedText := s.Find("div").Contents().Not(".label").Text()
```

Which ignores `elementC`, but not `elementD`, which has no outer tags.

HTML:

```
<li><span><h2>elementA</h2></span><div>elementB<br><span class="label">elementC</span>elementD</div></li>
```

How do I capture only `elementB` of `<div>`, and not `elementC` and `elementD`?

**Edit:**

I have tried closing the div tag like so:

```
s.Find(".label").BeforeHtml(`</div>`)
```

and also tried:

```
s.Find(".label").BeforeHtml(`</div><div>`)
```

and accessing the first `div`, disregarding the second `div` which should now have `elementD` with:

```
jp, _ := s.Find("div").First().Html()
```

However, this is not working. It seems that `</div>` must not be an open tag - it needs to be `<div>...</div>` to insert correctly. But this is NOT what I need, I require ONLY `</div>` or `</div><div>` to close the first `div` correctly.

What is the appropriate way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I can't edit the HTML with a 'broken' node, I have opted for this:

```
    s.Find(".label").BeforeHtml(`|_SEPARATOR_|`) // Insert text separator into Html
    preCleanNode := s.Find("div").Contents().Not(".label").Text() //Get Html as Text
    cleanNode := strings.Split(preCleanNode, `|_SEPARATOR_|`) // Split text based on Text Separator
    outputString := cleanNode[0] // Output our wanted text
```